# Transition Opacity w/javascript not working

Tags: javascript, css, css-transitions

I want to fadein a component after ajax call completes and jquery has rebuilt DOM.
I have this setup:
index.html:

```
<head>
<style>
      body {
        opacity: 0;
        transition: opacity 2s;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body onload="document.body.style.opacity='1'">
<div class="content">
<!-- Markup for content -->
</div>
</body>
```

main.css

```
.content {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 6s;
  transition: opacity 2s;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 6s;
  -moz-transition: opacity 6s;
}
```

main.js

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     const contentEl = document.querySelector(".content");

$(".submit").on("click", async function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    console.log(contentEl.style.opacity);

    if (contentEl.style.opacity == 1) {
      contentEl.style.opacity = 0;
      console.log("Style opacity is in if and = %s", contentEl.style.opacity);
    }
// Do Ajax and update DOM via jQuery

contentEl.style.opacity = 1;
}
```

The first time thru .content fades in as expected as well as fade in of whole page on initial render. However subsequent times thru there is no transition effect. Logging shows that I am changing style.opacity from 1 -> 0 and back to 1 after initial iteration. Any CSS guru's versed in CSS's dark secrets input advice appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    const contentEl = document.querySelector(".content");
    contentEl.style.opacity = 1; // Define initial opacity (starting val)
    $(".submit").on("click", async function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        contentEl.style.opacity = 0; // on click set opacity to 0?
        FadeIn(); // Let's Fade from 0 to 1!
    });

    let FadeIn = () => { // Function
        if (contentEl.style.opacity < 1) { // If opacity doesn't equal 1
            contentEl.style.opacity += 0.2; // Let's add 0.2!
            setTimeout(FadeIn(), 300); // Hell let's repeat that more 300ms
        }
    }; // Once we equal 1 we should be done

});
```

I don't play with the JQuery like that, I much rather too use CSS entirely for the animation process of these types of things, it's cleaner (less jitter). I'm assuming this is what you're sort of after though, a simple set value and slowly loop till finished. Button will start out 1 opacity, when clicked jump to 0 and slowly climb its way back up to 1.